# SQL Table for Groups ? Which solution would be better?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to setup groups in my network using MySQL. Users could join in groups or create groups. Of the two options below, I'm trying to identify which solution is better.

**First Solution:**

I create a Table called "Groups" with columns:

```
- GroupID
- GroupName
- Createtime
- GroupMembers...
```

In this solution I would save the users in the column `GroupMembers` like this "user1;/user2;/" and so on. This is my first solution; I don't know if this would be faster than the second solution. I just want to lookup `GroupMembers`, etc.

**Second Solution:**

I would create a table like in the first solution, but without the column `GroupMembers`, and I would create a second table for the `GroupMembers`.
This table will have following columns:

```
-GroupID //The ID of the group in the other table.
-UserID
```

When joins a group, it will be stored in the above table.

Comment: The second approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is Bad because it breaks normalization.

The second solution is Good.

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach would be to have a Users table, a Groups table and a UserGroups (or GroupUsers) table